# Rejecting broadcast of normal message from 10.55.56.23:39324 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Order: aborted

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, raft

facing the error frequently during my first transaction on any channel 
fabric version 1.4.2
orderering service : raft

**peer logs**

2019-12-05 10:00:41.232 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 959c89 [channel: qlqlchannel] Rejecting broadcast of normal message from 10.55.56.23:39324 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Order: aborted

**orderer logs**

2019-12-05 08:58:28.637 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] logSendFailure -> ERRO 9576ed Failed to send StepRequest to 2, because: aborted channel=qlqlchannel node=5

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with your raft setup as it doesn't have a leader I guess. Check if all of your orderers are working fine or not. There must be atleast 3 orderers up and running and communicating to each other so as to have a proper raft setup configured in your network. My suggestion is to go with atleast 5 orderers as if any one orderer(out of 5) gets out of sync, then also other orderers works fine by not failing the minimum 3 orderer requirement.

Comment: hi @trinayan  i have 8 orderer in my raft consensus all are working fine. i have observed closely all my orderers there is leader and all other are followers

Comment: Okay then check for the system channel if all those orderers have latest config block.